# Maximal regular sequence coincides with system of parameters

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, cohen-macaulay, regular-rings

I'm needing help in this question.

> Let $k$ be a field. Consider the $k$-algebra $R:=k[x,y,z,w]/(z+w,xy+xw)$ and define the ring $A$ the localization of $R$ in its maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} = (\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z},\overline{w})$. Prove that a sequence $a_1,\dots,a_n$ of elements of $\mathfrak{m}$ is system of parameters if and only if $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is  a regular sequence maximal.

Well, we know that every regular sequence is part of a system of parameters, so if $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is maximal regular sequence, then $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is part of system of parameters, but I'm not getting ace in the hole to solve this problem.

I think the correct approach to prove it is to prove that $A$ is Cohen-Macaulay. Can someone give me some hint?

Comment: The number of generators of $I=(z+w,xy+xw)$ is $2$, and height of $I$ is also $2$. Since $k[x,y,z,w]$ is CM, this shows $R$ is CM. Localization of $R$ is also CM.

Comment: Let me see. I didn't get it yet. Do These facts you said allow us to conclude that z+w, xy + xw is a regular sequence?

Comment: I tried to show A is a CM ring. Aren't you asking for this?

Comment: Yes, I got your intention. I want to know how did you conclude from facts:
($I$ has two generators and  height of $I$ equal to 2)
that $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay

Comment: Yes. In general, if $I=(x_1,..,x_n)$ is an ideal generated by $n$ elements in a CM ring $R$ such that $\operatorname{height}I=n$, then $R/I$ is a CM ring.

Answer (score 1):

First of all $$R\simeq k[x,y,z]/(x(y-z)).$$ This is clearly a Cohen-Macaulay ring, and $k[x,y,z]_{(x,y,z)}/(x(y-z))$ is a Cohen-Macaulay local ring. But in such a ring a system of parameters is a regular sequence.